# Express Server unexpected token when trying to test server connection

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I'm setting up a small facial recognition app with Clarifi API, I'm using express server and testing as I go with Postman. I have four endpoints:

- Signin - This is working fine
- Register - this is also working fine
- Profile - this is also working fine
- Image - This is where I'm coming unstuck

This is the code from my file server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const database = {
    users: [
        {
            id: '123',
            name: 'David',
            email: 'david@david.com',
            password: 'cookies',
            entries: 0,
            joined: new Date()

        },
        {
            id: '124',
            name: 'John',
            email: 'john@david.com',
            password: 'apples',
            entries: 0,
            joined: new Date()

        }
    ]
}
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(database.users)
})

app.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.email === database.users[0].email && 
        req.body.password === database.users[0].password){
            res.json('success')
        } else {
            res.status(400).json('error logging in');
        }
})

app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const { email, name, password } = req.body;
    database.users.push({
        id: '125',
            name: name,
            email: email,
            password: password,
            entries: 0,
            joined: new Date()
    })
    res.json(database.users[database.users.length-1])

})

app.get('/profile/:id', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    let found = false;
    database.users.forEach(user => {
        if (user.id === id) {
            found = true;
            return res.json(user);
        }
    })
    if (!found) {
        res.status(404).json('User not found');
    }
})

app.post('/image', (req, res) => {
    const {id} = req.body;
    let found = false;
    database.users.forEach(user => {
        if(user.id === id) {
            found = true;
            user.entries++
          return res.json(user.entries);
        }
    }) 
    if(!found){
        res.status(400).json('NOT FOUND'); 
    }
})  

app.listen(3000, ()=> {
    console.log('app is running on port 3000');
})
```

Everything works fine up until I add this part,

```
app.post('/image', (req, res) => {
    const {id} = req.body;
    let found = false;
    database.users.forEach(user => {
        if(user.id === id) {
            found = true;
            user.entries++
          return res.json(user.entries);
        }
    }) 
    if(!found){
        res.status(400).json('NOT FOUND'); 
    }
})
```

I know its pretty much the same function as profile, and I will eventually take it out and create it for use everywhere, but the main thing here is to get it to work on the final endpoint of creating entries for each time an image is uploaded for each user

Like I said, everything works in Postman up until this part of the code is added, plus, I am using VS code and there are no errors in the code and everything checks out on there, I also, ran npm start in the terminal and get the correct response of app is running on port 3000 before I try postman.

Below is a copy of the body output/error from Postman

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 16<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at JSON.parse (&lt;anonymous&gt;)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (C:\Users\djaad\Desktop\smart-brain-api\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\djaad\Desktop\smart-brain-api\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at invokeCallback (C:\Users\djaad\Desktop\smart-brain-api\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done (C:\Users\djaad\Desktop\smart-brain-api\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\djaad\Desktop\smart-brain-api\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:317:22)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1215:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

I have no idea what would be causing this, please can you help?

Thanks,

David.

Comment: can you add also your payload with postman?

Comment: Hello, thanks, I'm new to using the postman app, is this what you need?

Comment: POST http://localhost:3000/image
400
34ms
POST /image HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.24.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 1771c5a5-8206-4dd5-9cc5-6d44fac0abf3
Host: localhost:3000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 17
{
 "id": "124",
}
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 998
Date: Thu, 02 Apr 2020 07:38:30 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: This is the response you got from server. Add the request you sent to the server

Comment: Sorry {
 "id": "124",
}

Comment: I see a comma at the end of your request body? Can you remove it and try?

Comment: Wow!!! it works... absolutely brilliant, thanks for that. why would postman be telling me I have an unexpected } though? Never even give the request a thought as I was looking in my code! Thanks for that... Really appreciate it.

Comment: The unexpected } is the part after comma. Please make sure you understand the JSON syntax https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp